# How to Highlight Text in Yellow Using Apple Mail

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, apple-mail

Is it possible to highlight text in yellow (or another color) using OS X Apple Mail? There does not appear to be a simple way to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Apple.stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Apple.stackexchange

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note**: The complete list of detailed steps with pictures are posted here: http://www.mihalick.us/how-to-highlight-text-in-yellow-using-apple-mail/

Here is a summary of the steps:

1. Obtain some highlighted text in a method of your choosing. I composed an email in MS Outlook on Windows, highlighted some text and then sent that email to one of my accounts in Apple Mail. You can also simply copy some highlighted yellow text from a website page (use [this page](http://www.mihalick.us/how-to-highlight-text-in-yellow-using-apple-mail/), if you don't have one handy) by dragging over the text with your mouse and copying to your clipboard.
2. I copied the text out of that email (or the highlighted text above in step 1) and then pasted it into a new document in Apple's *TextEdit* application.
3. Then in my TextEdit document, I highlighted the text with my cursor, right clicked and selected   “Font | Styles…”
4. In the pop-up menu, click ‘Add to Favorites’, and then give your style a name. For example, 'Highlighted Yellow'. I didn’t check either option to include the font or ruler.
5. Click ‘Add’. Your new style for highlighting is now saved and can be used in Apple Mail by the following steps...

**Using the style in Apple Mail**

1. When you are composing a message in Apple Mail, using your cursor simply highlight the text whose background you want to highlight.  Then right click with the mouse and select “Font | Styles…”
2. Ensure the “Favorite Styles” option is selected and then choose your new “Highlighted Yellow” (or whatever you named it) style from the drop down list.
3. Click “Apply” and voila!

For the steps with pictures, you can visit: http://www.mihalick.us/how-to-highlight-text-in-yellow-using-apple-mail/

Comment: My version of TextEdit (1.11) has highlighting available on the toolbar, so I was able to combine steps 1 and 2 without Outlook. Why the capability did not migrate from TextEdit to Mail, 'tis a puzzlement.

Comment: Is there a way to manage styles, specifically to delete a style?

Comment: To remove a favorite style from the list, Open TextEdit, right click in the editor area, choose Font | Styles...  Then click on the 'Favorite Styles' radio button and choose the style you want to remove from the pull down list.  Finally, select the 'Remove From Favorites' button. You cannot remove the Default style.

Answer (score 11):

In macOS High Sierra (version 10.13) this is now quite easy. In Mail.app:

First bring up the tool bar, if you already don't have it enabled. This can be enabled by clicking the Tool bar that has the letter "A" on the top right corner of the composing window. Once you do this you can:

1. Select the text you want highlighted
2. Click on the 'Text Background Color' icon. This is shown as a small letter 'a' with a red diagonal line through it.
3. Select a highlight color.

That's all there is to it really.